# Merge the tag [tandem] into [hp-nonstop]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[Tandem Computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_Computers) servers are now [part of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_Computers#Acquisition_by_Hewlett_Packard,_TNS/E_migration_to_Itanium) the HPE server-line and are known as [HPE NonStop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NonStop_(server_computers)#Hardware) systems. Currently there are two tags, [tandem] and [hp-nonstop], which I think are referring to the same thing. Is it possible to merge the tag [tandem] into [hp-nonstop]?